# change number representation to indian

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wampserver

i need change number representation to 'Arabic-Indic digits' in my web application to display the 123456789 to "٠١٢٣٤٥٦٧٨٩" .

the following code do what i need but  over Jquery selected dom element like span .BUT i need to change all number on the whole response from the server

```
// Eastern Arabic (officially "Arabic-Indic digits")
      "0123456789".replace(/\d/g, function(v) {
                  return String.fromCharCode(v.charCodeAt(0) + 0x0630);
        });  // "٠١٢٣٤٥٦٧٨٩"
```

more info about my Application. 
 i use WampServer as webserver which mean i hope to get a solution using php,jquery,js,css , Apache server settings.

Comment: so basically, you have strings of `"0123456789"` all over your page, and you want to change that to arabic? or all digits in general?

Comment: can it be as simple as (server response string).replace(/\d/g, function(v) {
                  return String.fromCharCode(v.charCodeAt(0) + 0x0630);
        });

Comment: @Banana All Digit in general

Comment: @Ted How to do this over Response , how to pass the full response to  to this code

Comment: Bad idea mate, things like `someArray[2]` will turn into `someArray[٢]`

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
function convertArabic($str) {
        $standard = array("9", "8", "7", "6", "5", "4", "3", "2", "1", "0");
        $east_arabic = array("٠", "١", "٢", "٣", "٤", "٥", "٦", "٧", "٨", "٩");

        $str = str_replace($standard, $east_arabic, $str);
        return $str;
    }
```

pass a string it will replace digits to Arabic in the whole string

Comment: i need to fire my whole text to this method

Comment: yes just pass the server response string to this method it will replace all the numbers.

Comment: i use to do in the following way, i compose server response to a variable and before sending response to browser i bass the complete string to this url if language is arabic